Create File object from parsed CSV data
I'm currently working on a project that involves uploading a CSV file and doing some processing of that file. I'm using papa parse to get the data from the original file so I can modify it as needed:
const reader = new FileReader()

reader.onload = async ({ target }) => {
  const csv = Papa.parse(target?.result as any, {
    header: true
  })
  const parsedData: any[] = csv?.data;
  setOriginalData(parsedData);
}

reader.readAsText(file)

I then hit an API endpoint to map through the data and modify it as needed. Once it's been modified, I need to convert it back to a file object so I can upload it to an S3 bucket through my API. After processing, the data has the shape of:
[
  {
    Col_1: 'value_1',
    Col_2: 'value_2,
    ...
  },
  ...
]

I need to take this data and translate it into a File object in order for the upload endpoint to work.
I've spent some time digging into documentation, but there seems to be more focus on downloading the data as a CSV file (such as with libraries like react-csv). I need to save both the original and processed files, and this is how I'm currently trying to approach it:
const originalFormData = new FormData();
originalFormData.append('file', file);

const uploadOriginalRes = await fetch('/api/lists/save', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: originalFormData
})
const originalJsonRes = await uploadOriginalRes.json();

const fileName = originalJsonRes.data.filename;
const processedFile = new File(processData, `${fileName}-processed`, { type: 'text/csv' })

const processedFormData = new FormData();
processedFormData.append('file', processedFile)

const processedFileUploadRes = await fetch('/api/lists/save', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: processedFormData
})

const processedFileJsonRes = await processedFileUploadRes.json();
console.log('PROCESSED FILE:', processedFileJsonRes);

The file that I'm uploading in the first API call is read directly from the file input, and is saved as a csv file the way I expect it to. But somewhat unsurprisingly, the resulting CSV file from the call where I'm trying to upload the processed data looks like this:
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]...

I'm not sure how I need to modify the data to have it be read properly as CSV data.

Before the CSV file can be uploaded, you need to format it before creating the File object. Since your processed data is in the form of an array of objects, you need to convert it into a CSV string first.
import Papa from 'papaparse';

// Assuming here that processData is your array of objects
const processData = [
  { Col_1: 'value_1', Col_2: 'value_2' },
  // More objects...
];

// Convert processed data to CSV string
const csvContent = Papa.unparse(processData);

console.log(csvContent);

So, this is now a CSV string representing your data. Then create a Blob object from this CSV string and use it to create a File object.
// Create a Blob object from the CSV string
const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv' });

// Create a File object from the Blob
const processedFile = new File([blob], `${fileName}-processed.csv`);

console.log(processedFile);

Now, processedFile is a File object with the processed CSV data, which you can use to upload to your API endpoint.
